# Linq GroupBy and take the entry which is not null

Tags: c#, linq

The class Selection has 4 properties:

```
public class Selection
{
    string IdSelectionType {get; set;}
    string Name {get; set;}
    decimal? OddValue {get; set;}
    bool Visible {get; set;}
}
```

The examples data

```
var originalList = new List<Selection>()
        {
            new Selection() {IdSelectionType = "1", Name = "Under (75.50)", Visible = true},
            new Selection() {IdSelectionType = "2", Name = "Under (75.50)", Visible = true},
            new Selection() {IdSelectionType = "1", Name = "Under (75.50)", OddValue = 1.840m, Visible = true},
            new Selection() {IdSelectionType = "2", Name = "Under (75.50)", OddValue = 1.860m, Visible = true},
        };
```

I'd like to select a list where the elements with OddValue = null are discarded if there is another element which is identical but with the OddValue != null.

Is there any Linq / MoreLinq operator to do something similar?

```
Selections.GroupBy(s =>
          new {s.IdSelectionType, s.Name, s.OddValue, s.Visible})
          .Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

[image]

The expected result would be:
[image]

Comment: Your code and your screenshot don't agree - the code has `OddValue`, and the screenshot has `OddValure`. What's up with that?

Comment: And OddValue in your class is not nullable ;)
What is with entries which have only OddValue: null? Do you want to get them as well?

Comment: If you `GroupBy` all the columns and take the `First`, that's just the same as doing `Distinct`.  Also your class has 4 properties, but in the Linq query you group on 5.

Comment: After GroupBy discluding OddValue and order by OddValue (null values last), You can Select a new object with all key properties and value.First(which is OddValue)

Comment: You can try  `.Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.OddValue != null))`.
It will choose the first non null it finds and if there isn't one it will return the default which is null.

Comment: @WaiHaLee: I don't know.. it's funny because I have checked the code and it's correct. The image compression did a very weird job

Comment: @MightyBadaboom: corrected. I want OddValue null only if I don't have OddValue in another entry

Comment: Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = items.OrderBy(x => x.Name)
                  .ThenByDescending(x => x.OddValue)
                  .GroupBy(s => new {s.IdSelectionType, s.Name, s.Visible})
                  .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
                  .ToList();
```

First order the items by `Name` and `OddValue` then group by `Name`. You will have the entries with `OddValue != null` before the entries with `OddValue == null`. Then take the first entry of each grouping.

This will return the entries with `OddValue == null` and no other entry with the same `Name`, too.

The final result: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jZ5gs2

Comment: There is something which is not working.. the other example works well.

Comment: Would be nice if you would tell me what's not working ;)

Comment: Fixed, now it's really nice

Comment: actually it wasn't a real mistake by you. The data set from the other user was different from the real one (and I didn't realized). So grouping just by name it was returning only one element.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Union. Select all elements which don't have OddValue == null and then union the remaining (those with null) against the first list.

https://linqsamples.com/linq-to-objects/set/Union

```
var originalList = new[]
        {
            new Selection() {IdSelectionType = "1", Name = "Under (75.50)", Visible = true},
            new Selection() {IdSelectionType = "2", Name = "Under (75.50)", Visible = true},
            //new Selection() {IdSelectionType = "1", Name = "Under (75.50)", OddValue = 1.840m, Visible = true},
            new Selection() {IdSelectionType = "2", Name = "Under (75.50)", OddValue = 1.860m, Visible = true},
        };

        var noneNulls = originalList.Where(ol => ol.OddValue != null);

        var endList = originalList
            .Where(ol => !noneNulls.Select(nn => nn.IdSelectionType).Contains(ol.IdSelectionType))
            .Union(noneNulls);
```

The working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UJ8FaS

Comment: But it seems like he want's the entries where 'OddValue == null' without another entry with the same Name, too.

Comment: Yes? He can union the result with by comparing set parameters and select all parameters. Or he could use an except to create the list... either way is good.